# Nginx rewrite rule with regex

Tags: php, nginx

Please help me in this problem. I want to rewrite url in this way:
This is what i write into the browser mysite.com/somepage.php
And I want to rewrite it to this: mysite.com/index.php?page=somepage so the index.php can handle the page load.

My conf in nginx:

```php
location ~ ^\/(.*)\.php$ {
    rewrite ^\/(.*)\.php$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}
```

My PHP index file part:

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET" && isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page = $_GET['page'];
      switch ($page) {
        case 'somepage':
          include 'php/somepage.php';
          break;
        default:
          include 'php/login.php';
          break;
      }
    } else {
      include 'php/login.php';
    }
```

I tested the regex on regex101.com.
https://prnt.sc/uKone5srB8qq

This redirection gives 404 error.

Comment: As `index.php` matches the pattern for `somepage.php`, how is your configuration treating `index.php` differently?

Comment: You need to configure PHP-FPM to handle your PHP files.

Comment: I tried this if but it doesn't solved it if (!-e $request_filename)

Comment: Instead of a complicated RegEx to match a very specific pattern and jamming it in the QS, would the native [`try_files`](https://serverfault.com/a/1094257/75021) along with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` be an option?

Comment: @ChrisHaas it doesn't work

Comment: @IstvánSzabó, without know what you tried, I'm unable to help you further.

Comment: @ChrisHaas i tried this: `location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php74-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}`